# win32com.client self terminating issue

Tags: python, excel, win32com, spyder

I am using Python 3.3.5 and trying to save an Excel 2003 file (.xls) as Excel 2007 file (.xlsx). The problem with the following scripts  is that the script is working very well if I run it inside of Spyder, however if I try to run it simply double-clicking on script, it does not working.

Spyder can import win32com.client with no problem and run the script successfully while IDLE can not run the script and gives that error:

"import win32api, sys, os "

"ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."

Excel_File_Conversion Script through win32com.client

```
fname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xls;*.xlsx"),
                                              ("All files", "*.*") ))
fname = fname.replace("/",os.path.sep)
if fname[-1] != 'x':
    try:
        import win32com.client as win32 
        excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(fname)
        messagebox.showinfo(title = "Conversion",
                            message="Excel 2003(.xls) format was converted to Excel 2007(.xlsx) format",
                            detail = "Press OK to continue")
        wb.SaveAs(fname+"x", FileFormat = 51)
        wb.Close()
        excel.Application.Quit()
        fname = fname+"x"
    except TypeError:
        messagebox.showerror(title = "Error", message="File could not be opened")
```

PS: I have no problem with running scripts by double clicking.

Comment: Are you running the script on the same computer you have Spyder installed on? It sounds like you need to install pywin32. Try installing it from this location: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

Comment: yes, definitely same computer, it is strange because scripts starts running, but then terminates suddenly without giving any error.

Comment: Inside Spyder you can select to run your script in an external terminal (changing your preferences with F6) to see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `pywin32` doesn't always install correctly. There's a few things you can try (in this order):

- In a command prompt (you may have to right-click and "Run as Administrator") run `python C:\Python33\Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install`
- Add the path of where you find the `pythoncom33.dll` to your Windows PATH. It might be under the Python root directory or further down.
- Copy the `pythoncom33.dll`to `C:\Python33\Lib\site-packages\win32`
- Otherwise you might want to try one of the distributions that already come with `pywin32`included like `Anaconda` or `Canopy` or `WinPython`

Always adjust your path accordingly.