# Error by import win32com.client

Tags: windows, python-3.x, pywin32

I use win 10， Python 3.5.2 and pywin32-220.win-amd64-py3.5 (all 64-bit). And python and pywin32 are installed in the default path. In my case it's `C:\Users\xx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35`.

When I `import win32com.client`, the error was like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import win32com.client   File "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/win32com/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import win32api, sys, os ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Then I searched in SO, I found some solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24472615/win32com-client-self-terminating-issue).

When I tried again, it was still going wrong.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/win32com/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    SetupEnvironment()
  File "C:/Users/xx/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python35/Lib/site-packages/win32com/__init__.py", line 47, in SetupEnvironment
    __path__.append( win32api.GetFullPathName( __path__[0] + "\\..\\win32comext") )
NameError: name '__path__' is not defined
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try removing pywin32 and pip install [pypiwin32](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32).

Comment: What is the difference between them? @eryksun

Comment: The wheel package doesn't run the post-install script that copies the DLLs to the system directory, but you don't need that to import `win32com.client`.

Comment: @eryksun It worked finally. THANK YOU SO MUCH!